Bluetooth is not turning on NetHunter Android
I am using Kali NetHunter on a rooted Android device, and I'm encountering an issue with Bluetooth. Whenever I try to enable Bluetooth through the GUI or using the command line, it simply doesn't turn on. I can see the Bluetooth icon, but it stays stuck on "Turning on."
It was working in the beginning, I could connect to headphone, I sent a video file from PC to tablet via Bluetooth.
service bluetooth status

bluetooth is not running ... failed!

Then I started
service bluetooth restart

Stopping bluetooth: /usr/sbin/bluetoothd.
Starting bluetooth: bluetoothd.

but this does not restart the Bluetooth. Right after start command, service Bluetooth status still says "Bluetooth is not running ... failed!"
I already run those commands:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth

lsusb command shows this:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

It does not show anything about the Bluetooth adapter
I also added kali-tools-bluetooth, but this did not help either.
